# How do I replace a substring that appears more than once in a string?

Tags: flash

I am curious on how to replace all the instances of '(A)' in a string with just 'A'.

This is what I have, but it is not working:

```
String str = "(A) + (B) + ( (A) + (B) )";
str = str.replace("(A)","A");
```

Thanks,
Y_Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have do do it in a loop, that is:

```
while(str.indexOf(pattern) != -1) str.replace(pattern, replacement);
```

Look at adobe's documentation, too. It usually knows the answer. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html